# How does the JavaScript heap handle recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion, heap-memory

Hi my question above is a little vague so I'll try to make it clearer.

I have code of the form:

```
function main () {

  async function recursive () {
     var a = "Hello World";
     var b = "Goodbye World";

     recursive();

  }
  recursive();

}
```

I am running into an issue where I am running out of heap memory.

Assuming what I showed above is how my program behaves, with a and b being declared within the recursive function, my question is whether the variables are destroyed upon the call to recursive within the recursive function or whether they will persist until there are no more recursive calls and the main function reaches its endpoint assuming I keep the main function running long enough for that to happen.

I'm worried they stay alive in the heap and since my real program stores large strings in those variables I'm worried that that is the reason I'm running out of heap.

Comment: Your missing an `await recursive()`,.  In theory this should stop the heap running out,.  But there was a similar question today that showed Chrome at least optimizing away the `async`..  Although doing `await Promise.resolve()` prevents this->  see this thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554274/run-repetetive-task-in-node-js?noredirect=1#comment90077130_51554274

Comment: I need the calls to recursive to run in parallel which is why I'm not awaiting. Is not awaiting going to cause the un awaited promise to go to the heap anyway?

Comment: If your not awaiting with a least some form of throttling, then of course the heap will fill up,..`the un awaited promise to go to the heap anyway?` Indeed, and that's were your problem lies..  Your infinitely pushing promises onto the heap, you need some form of throttling.

Comment: poorly. it has no tco

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript does not (*yet*?) have tail call optimization for recursion, so for sure you'll eventually fill up your *call stack*. The reason your heap is filling up is because `recursive` is defined as an `async` function and never waits for the allocated `Promise` objects to resolve. This will fill up your *heap* because the garbage collector doesn't have the chance to collect them.

In short, recursion doesn't use up the heap unless you're allocating things in the heap within your functions.

Expansion of what's happening:

```
main
  new Promise(() => {
    new Promise(() => {
      new Promise(() => {
        new Promise(() => {
          new Promise(() => { //etc.
```

You say you're not awaiting Promises because you want things to run in parallel. This is a dangerous approach for a few reasons. Promises should always be awaited in case they throw, and of course you want to make sure that you're allocating predictable amounts of memory usage. If this recursive function means you're getting an unpredictable number of needed tasks, you should consider a task queue pattern:

```
const tasks = [];

async function recursive() {
  // ...
  tasks.push(workItem);
  // ...
}

async function processTasks() {
  while (tasks.length) {
    workItem = tasks.unshift();

    // Process work item. May provoke calls to `recursive`
    // ...do awaits here for the async parts
  }
}

async function processWork(maxParallelism) {
  const workers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < maxParallelism; i++) {
    workers.push(processTasks());
  }

  await Promise.all(workers);
}
```

Finally, in case it needs to be said, `async` functions don't let you do parallel processing; they just provide a way to more conveniently write Promises and do sequential and/or parallel waits for async events. JavaScript remains a single-threaded execution engine unless you use things like web workers. So using async functions to try to parallelize *synchronous* tasks won't do anything for you.

Comment: Would the call to recursive() make a promise on the heap even if I'm not awaiting on it? And if that's the case when will it ever leave the heap? Also thanks for quick reply

Comment: Async functions start executing _synchronously_, and the Promise isn't returned until something is awaited or returned. You've got a synchronous infinite recursive loop that's just allocating Promise after Promise. Is there an actual thing you're trying to do? Using Promises normally doesn't have any issues, but you're definitely not doing something normal unless you're just monkeying around to see what happens.

Comment: Yah it does some stuff each recursive call. The stuff it does I can't say, but I can say that it does that stuff correctly for a few hundred iterations then crashes due to insufficient heap size. The recursive call is also intended to grab more items to recurse on

Comment: I suspect you need your code sample to reflect something closer to what's actually being done. We might have more practical suggestions. If your call patterns are more normal and your heap is filling up, you might want to consider making more like a task queue and using a fixed-size worker pool.

Comment: Added hopefully useful sample of capping your parallel workers.

Comment: Safari has tail call optimization; other browsers have not implemented it yet: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Finally a reason to not hate Safari?

Comment: @HereticMonkey  Seen as blocking the main thread is not a good idea, tail call optimization is likely not a high priority for most browser vendors.  Saying this for web-workers & blocking node.js processes it's certainly a nice addition if Google can update the V8 engine for it.

Comment: The only real use case for TCO IMO is being able to write algorithms that are more elegantly expressed using recursion without getting stack overflows.

Comment: @Keith sure, and that page I linked to includes Node.js and other JS runtimes outside of browsers too. It appears as though there is only one that supports TCO: [XS6](https://github.com/Kinoma/kinomajs)...